# Ajax call to complete success, before actually completing the call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out an ajax call... I need the call to hold up and finish loading HTML contents, before going over once again (it is triggered by keyup event)... Otherwise returned HTML is actually loaded multiple times. In my case the ajax call returns HTML which then executes a JS function. But when it gets loaded multiple times, JS function is executed twice = bad.

Here is my code (alert boxes are only for help...):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var isProcessing = false;

   $('#productSearchInput').keyup(function() {

   var productSearchInput = $(this).val();
   var dataString = 'searchInput='+ productSearchInput;
   var script_url = '../ajax/service-search.php';

    if(productSearchInput.length > 3 && isProcessing === false) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: script_url,
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend:     
            function() {    
            isProcessing = true;
                            alert('Processing input: ' + productSearchInput;
            },
        success:
            function(server_response)   {
            $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show('fast', function() { alert('Currently processing...');  } );  
            },
        error:
            function() {
            alert('ajax call failed...');
            },
        complete: 
            function() {
            isProcessing = false;
                            alert('Processing done');
            }
        });

    }

  return false;
  });
});
```

What is wrong is, that the "Processing done" alert appears before the "Wait for processing" alert... And then after "Processing done" alert has showed, the "Wait for processing" alert shows.

I need my HTML server_response to show, before completing the call and setting isProcessing = false;...

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. Using `show` method requires some time for animation, so callback is called after complete. Why not to simplify your code to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: script_url,
    data: dataString,
    beforeSend: function() {    
        isProcessing = true;
        alert('Processing input: ' + productSearchInput);
        },
    success: function(server_response)   {
        alert('Wait for processing...');
        $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show('fast', function() { 
            alert('Processing done');
            isProcessing = false;
        });                    
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('ajax call failed...');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is where I started ;)

The reason why I need the call to wait for HTML to load, is that somtimes I'm scanning a barcode. When I scan a barcode, the HTML never gets loaded before it dissappears again. I can then hit a random key, because the ajax call is triggered by keyup - which then reads the digits I have scanned. I have tried setting the barcodescanner with ENTER as terminator, but it all happens too quickly - since the HTML is not yet loaded.

Comment: Maybe you can give more detailed information or example on jsfiddle so that users can reproduce your problem? Maybe `xhr.abort()` or `setTimeout` can help to avoid excessive ajax calls/content reloading ?

Comment: If i make a simple example, everything is fine... The .php I'm loading HTML from, ofcourse includes mySQL queries. I'm pretty sure my ajax call completes faster than the mySQL queries in my PHP file, which causes the the ajax call to start over, before any HTML is returned...

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, instead of **isProcessing**?

Please check the code in this case (something like this):

```
     var isProcessing = $.Deferred();

     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: script_url,
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() {    
            alert('Processing input: ' + productSearchInput);
        },
        success: function(server_response) {
            alert('Wait for processing...');
            $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show('fast', isProcessing.resolve);                    
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('ajax call failed...');
        }
    });
    $.when(isProcessing).then(function(){alert('Processing done');});
```

Comment: Didn't change anything ... I've updated my script to include a few more statements...